# How to import names from a facebook or google contact list into an app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean

I made a barebones contact app from a Heroku tutorial 
https://faucontactlist.herokuapp.com/#/
and want to include first names and last names into the app

Comment: r u using any fb of g+ login for ur app?

Comment: I'm willing to use whichever

Comment: if like that u need to store them some where while sign up  and get them where ever u want

Comment: Yeah, what kind of code does that?